# How can I remove element from list?

Tags: python

Attempts to remove characters from the string that are not numbers. Unfortunately, I cannot do this due to a reason. I also tried "del file[i][j]", unfortunately without.

Code:

```
file_open = open("napisy.txt","r")
wyniki = open("wyniki4.txt","w")
file = file_open.read().split()
file1 = file
print(file)
cyfry = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
cyfry_zad3 = ''
licznik_cyfr = 0
tab = []
for i in range(0,len(file1)):
    for j in range(0,len(file1[i])):
        if file1[i][j] not in cyfry:
            file1.remove(file1[i][j])
            #del file1[i][j]
print(file1)
```

result

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  

Are you trying to create a second with strings from the first file 'filtered' to remove numbers?

Comment: This should help : https://www.csestack.org/difference-between-remove-del-pop-python-list/

Comment: To begin with, strings are immutable, you can't just remove elements from one, you need to create a new string without those characters. Second, you're trying to remove whole lines of the file, not just characters in one of the lines, the entire logic is wrong.

Comment: are you trying to remove all the characters that are not numbers?

Comment: @crazycat256 yes

Comment: @MariusROBERT okay, but what if I don't know the index I want to delete, like in this case?

Comment: @QarRaQ it's all explained in the link : use `remove` if you have the value, `del` or `pop` if you have the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```py
file_open = open("napisy.txt","r")
file = file_open.read()
file_open.close()

for char in list(file):
    if char not in "1234567890":
        file = file.replace(char, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making it all simpler?

```
bad_characters = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'] 
file_text = file.read()
file_text = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c not in bad_characters, file_text))
```

A novice-friendly version:

```
bad_characters = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'] 
file_text = file.read()
good_text = ""
for character in file_text:
    if character not in bad_characters:
        good_text += character 
print(good_text)
```

Comment: Its too complicate for me, I need simple version, 
I have recently started learning this language